# Fetch record from DynamoDB with 2 conditions and without using scan

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to fetch data from DynamoDB with 2 conditions.

Example: Condition's are If `(isValue==true or xdate < todaysDate)` then fetch. I need to implement this without using Scan. Because scan takes lot of time. In this case isValue is Global Secondary Index. Please let me know how I can fetch based on `(isValue==true or xdate < todaysDate)`. I am using typescript to connect to DynamoDB.

```
[P-key] [Sort-key]  [GSI]   
ID          SID    isValue       xdate 
1          234566   TRUE    2021-10-07T10:33:44Z
2          645567   FALSE   2021-10-06T10:33:44Z
3          546688   FALSE   2021-10-07T10:33:44Z
4          545678   TRUE    2021-10-05T10:33:44Z
```

Comment: Please show us the table and key layout as well as some sample data.

Comment: Is `xdate` the sort key?

Comment: No isValue is GSI and xdate is normal attribute. I have different attribute for Partition key and Sort key. But in this particular scenario I need data based on  (isValue==true or xdate < todaysDate) condition only

Comment: Then you cannot do that query without scan.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve what you want without using the `scan` operation.  The first that comes to mind is known as a "sparse index".

You have created a Global Secondary Index (GSI) on the `isValue` attribute, which is a great start!  Instead of creating a boolean field where the *value* of the `isValue` field determines if the value exists, considering including the attribute on the item *only* when `isValue` is true.

In your above example, that would mean that items with ID 1 and 4 would include the `isValue` attribute, and items with ID 2 and 3 would *not* include the `isValue` attribute.  For example:

[image]

DynamoDB will only include items with the `isValue` attribute in the GSI, which then allows you to query the GSI based on the date range.  Your GSI would look like this:

[image]

In this example, you likely *wouldn't* use a GSI partition key of `isValue`, since `true` isn't a particularly compelling partition key (maybe use the `ID` of the item instead). However, this example is meant to illustrate how you could filter items in DynamoDB using a GSI instead of a boolean attribute.

Comment: While this is useful, it doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: I don't see a specific question posed by OP, so I had to do a bit of interpretation.  It sounds like the question is "how do I fetch data from DynamoDb using filters on non-primary key attributes without using the scan operation?".  The answer is a bit nuanced, but I think I've outlined one strategy to achieve what OP wanted.  If it's not clear how my answer addresses OP's problem, I'm open to suggestions on how to improve the answer.

Comment: In my opinion, the answer is - it is not possible using a query as the partition key name and value must be specified as an equality condition. Using a sparse index strategy you've mentioned in your answer, the OP's requirement of condition when isValue is FALSE but xdate is less than todaysDate would not be satisfied :)

Comment: The access pattern is "fetch items where isValue is TRUE and xdate is < today's date".  The GSI I created includes only items where isValue is true, leaving only the date range condition left to deal with.  Thus, this access pattern could be implemented by executing a query against the GSI where the sort key (date) is less than today.  Perhaps I could add that query to the answer to make this point clear.

Comment: It's an `or` condition in the question.